# How to write a policy in Oracle SQL that restricts the access to non-owners for a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to restrict non-owners (excluding sys dba) from accessing the table *i.e.* users can access only the data of their own but `sysdba` should be able to access any data without restrictions. Finally, I want to attach the policy to the table.

For eg:
This is the table:

```
id name score
1 SYS 4
2 RHWTT 5
3 LEO 4
4 MOD3_ADMIN 5
5 VPD674 4
6 SCOTT 5
7 HR 4
8 OE 5
9 PM 4
10 IX 5
11 SH 4
12 BI 5
13 IXSNEAKY 4
14 DVF 5
```

This table is created by A and B is able to run select queries. I want to design and attach a policy that lets only A and sys_dba access to this table.

I read [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/accessre.htm#i1007217) but could not deduce the logic for my case. I am new to Oracle SQL as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do absolutely anything about it.

Tables (and data stored within) are owned by user A. Nobody can see it **unless** user A grants  certain privileges to other users, such as user B.

That can be done by granting select privilege, i.e.

```
grant select on my_table to user_B;
```

and user B would then fetch data as

```
select * from user_A.my_table;
```

User B won't be able to modify data (as it wasn't granted insert/update/delete).

Furthermore, you (as user A) can create a **view** which selects only part of data, e.g.

```
create view v_my_table as 
  select * 
  from my_table
  where score > 4;

grant select on v_my_table to user_B;
```

Doing so, user B would see only rows whose score is larger than 4.

---

If there's user C, it can't see absolutely anything. If you'd want it to see some data, you'd do what you already did with user B - grant certain privileges.

However, there's an option to let user B "forward" privileges to other users - you'd use `with grant option`, e.g.

```
grant select on my_table to user_B with grant option;
```

That would allow user B to grant select to other users, e.g.

```
grant select on user_A.my_table to user_C;
```

---

Finally (talking about this answer), if there are many users you'd want to grant such privileges to, you can create **roles**. Then you'd grant privileges to a role, and grant role to another user(s). It allows you to modify roles depending on your (and other users') wishes.

```
create role my_role;
grant select on my_table to my_role;
```

For example, for beginning, you could grant `select` to `my_role`, and then grant `my_role` to users B, C and D.

```
grant my_role to user_B;
grant my_role to user_C;
```

Later, you can grant `insert` to `my_role`

```
grant insert on my_table to my_role;
```

and all users granted `my_role` would automatically be able to insert rows into user A's my_table.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you also take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59119590/how-to-return-rows-based-on-the-database-user-and-the-tables-contents ?