# How to return rows based on the database user and the table's contents?

Tags: oracle, stored-functions

I have a following table:

```
id name       score
 1 SYS        4
 2 RHWTT      5
 3 LEO        4
 4 MOD3_ADMIN 5
 5 VPD674     4
 6 SCOTT      5
 7 HR         4
 8 OE         5
 9 PM         4
10 IX         5
11 SH         4
12 BI         5
13 IXSNEAKY   4
14 DVF        5
```

I want to create a policy function in Oracle SQL that makes sure of the following things:

1. If a user(Leo) is executing a select statement on this table, it only gets `3 LEO 4`.
2. sys_dba gets all the results no matter what.

I have given select permissions to Leo on this table created by Scott.

I am getting stuck at writing this complex PL/SQL function. I tried the following and it states compilation errors. Also, I think it does not do what I intend to do:

```
CREATE FUNCTION no_show_all (
    p_schema    IN NUMBER(5),
    p_object    IN VARCHAR2
)
    RETURN 
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 'select avg(score) from scott.rating';
END;
/
```

Comment: Huh?  Sorry, but your function does not make any sense.  So you want to limit which records are selected based on a oracle username?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And sys_dba gets all records.

Comment: If you have at least version 11 (¿release 2?}, you might want to look into „label security“.

Comment: @Abecee - I think you meant [Virtual Private Database](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/vpd.htm#DBSEG007) (as Label Security is a chargeable extra to the Enterprise Edition). But even VPD requires EE and is not available in the Standard Edition, although intriguingly it is supported in Oracle 18c XE.

Comment: @APC: Actually, I had really label security in mind. As it seems do address exactly this scenario. But it was just a technology related comment - ignoring any licensing issues.

Comment: @Abecee - Unfortunately with Oracle we can't avoid licensing issues. And Label Security seems somewhat over-engineered for a relatively straightforward requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your previous question and info you posted, here's how I understood the question: if you granted `select` on the whole table to any user, then it is able to fetch **all** rows from it. You have to further restrict values.

One option - as we're talking about the function - is to use `case` in `where` clause.

Here's an example.

Sample data:

```
SQL> create table rating as
  2    select 1 id, 'sys' name, 4 score from dual union all
  3    select 3,    'leo'     , 3 from dual union all
  4    select 6,    'scott'   , 5 from dual union all
  5    select 7,    'hr'      , 2 from dual;

Table created.
```

Function:

- it accepts username as a parameter (mind letter case! In my example, everything is lowercase. In your, perhaps you'll have to use `upper` function or something like that)
- `case` says: if `par_user` is equal to `sys`, let it fetch all rows. Otherwise, fetch only rows whose name column's value is equal to `par_user`
- return the result

So:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_rating (par_user in varchar2)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    retval number;
  5  begin
  6    select avg(score)
  7      into retval
  8      from rating
  9      where name = case when par_user = 'sys' then name
 10                        else par_user
 11                   end;
 12    return retval;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.
```

Let's try it:

```
SQL> select f_rating('sys') rating_sys,
  2         f_rating('hr')  rating_hr
  3  from dual;

RATING_SYS  RATING_HR
---------- ----------
       3,5          2

SQL>
```

Comment: To me, this seems to restrict the result based on the function’s parameter rather than the user executing it. Apart from the fact, OP seems (to me at least) to ask for a solution effective for ordinary ˋSELECTˋ. What am I missing, please?

Comment: You're missing the first sentence I wrote, @Abecee. This question is related to previous one posted by the same person.

Comment: That previous question seems to be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59118281/how-to-write-a-policy-in-oracle-sql-that-restricts-the-access-to-non-owners-for - which is asking about implementing a security policy… Never mind.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a view for each user, like so

```
create view THE_VIEW as select * from TABLE where NAME = user
```

Then grant access to the view only.
Now it doesn't matter what kind of query a user tries to perform on your table, she will only get one row back.
Of-course the DBA user can access all the table data.